# Does the mutators apply here?

Tags: java, abstract-class, getter-setter

I have this question, this is the diagram that I was given, and I have managed to come with a solution, but the actual question itself is asking me to implement the get and set methods, which I am not sure if they are applicable here,

[image]

[image]

This is just part of the a bit long question, did not want to make it look like I want my homework done by the users here by pasting the whole question, but just a doubt, if get and set methods indeed can be implemented how can I do that?

So this is my code, what I have come with so far

```
public abstract class Property 
{
    private static int autonumber = 0, propID,area,price;
    private String address;

    public Property(String addr, int area,int price)
    {
        autonumber++;
        propID = autonumber;
        this.area = area;
        this.price = price;
    }
     public abstract double calculateMiscFee();

     public int getArea()
     {
         return area;
     }

     public void setArea()
     {

     }
//     public double calculateMiscFee()
//     {
//         return 100*
//     }
}
```

This is the latest code I have

```
public abstract class Property 
{
    private static int autonumber = 0;
    private int propID;
    private int area;
    private double price;
    private String address;
    private int district;

    public Property(String addr, int area,double price, int district)
    {
        autonumber++;
        propID = autonumber;
        this.area = area;
        this.price = price;
        this.district = district;
        this.address = addr;

    }
     public abstract double calculateMiscFee();

     public int getArea()
     {
         return area;
     }

     public void setArea(int a)
     {
         area = a;
     }

      public String getAddress()
     {
         return address;
     }

     public void setAddress(String add)
     {
         address = add;
     }

     public double getPrice()
     {
         return price; 
     }
     public  void setPrice(double p) 
     { 
          price = p;
     }

     public int getDistrict()
     {
         return district;
     }

     public  void setDistrict(int disc) 
     { 
          district = disc;
     }
//     public double calculateMiscFee()
//     {
//         return 100*
//     }

      public String toString()
      {

      }

}
```

Comment: Your scanned question is impossible to read. Can you edit your question to make it clear what you are asking? Are you just wondering how to implement getters and setters for a class?

Comment: Sorry duncan my office proxy doesnot allow me to view the images, so i did not know it was that bad

Comment: Your constructor is already setting the area and price for the property. Your setters would do the very same thing, but for one of them at a time. `getArea` looks right to me...

Comment: @DuncanJones now it should be clear..

Comment: @JacobRaihle so can I conclude that area is the only mutable variable here? just want to get clarification

Comment: @JacobRaihle if I do the setarea then I dont required this line of code this.area = area; do I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

propID, area and price should not be `static`. `static` variables are shared between all instances of a class, and these variables should be per instance, just like address.

If a class declares a variable `abc` of type `String`, the getter and setter for `abc` would look like the following:

```
public String getAbc() {
    return abc;
}

public void setAbc(String newAbc) {
    /* Potentially do some validation of the new value
     * For example make sure it's not null, or inside reasonable ranges
     * (A price shouldn't be negative, etc.)
     */
    abc = newAbc;
}
```

`toString()` is a method which already exists in all classes, but you can still override it. For example:

```
class MyClass {
    private int myInt;

    public MyClass(int myInt) {
        this.myInt = myInt;
    }

    @Overrides
    public String toString() {
        return "MyClass with value " + myInt;
    }
}
```

Comment: hey tks for this, I have updated my original post with the latest working, please see that. Also in the question it is mentioned that there have to be a toString() method to dispaly all the attributes how to do that, I am confused because toString is a built in method right?

Answer (score 0):

since you need getters and setters for all your private fields that an be used outside of this class, like propertyID is  needed for customer. So you have to code the getters and setters for propertyID. Hope this satisfies your ques.

Comment: PropertyID probably shouldn't be mutable.

Comment: but propertyID is autogenerated, as the Property class explains that it is system generated, what you say?

Answer (score 0):

Your attributes must be declared separately like

`private static int autonumber = 0, 

private static int propID     = 0;

private static int area       = 0;

private static int price      = 0;`

then add getters & setters by just **appending get or set and capitalizing the first letter of the variable.** Like this

`getAutonumber 

setAutonumber`
 etc.

And finally,
If it's a getter, the method should return int with no parameter.
If it's a setter, the method should return void with and a parameter of int.

Like this:

`public static int   getAutoNumber()       { return autonumber; } 

public static void setAutoNumber(int an) { autonumber = an; }`

public static int   getPropID()           { return propID; }
public static void setPropID(int pi)     { propID = pi; }

public static int   getArea()             { return area; }
public static void setArea(int a)        { area = a; }

public static int  getPrice()            { return price; }
public static void setPrice(int p)       { price = p;}

Comment: if I do the setter and getters then I dont require this line of code this.area = area; do I?

Comment: You can, but you would not want to. You will still need >>>this.area = area;<<< in the setter, because, that is the idea of a setter, you are 'setting' the value of the variable through the 'setter' method. It would be no use if you remove that line.

Comment: Oh understood, another thing that most of the people seem to miss is that the question also asked for district I think that can be implemented as mutable right?

Comment: You don't want to expose autoNumber, it's purely an implementation thing. You don't want propID to be mutable. You only want autoNumber to be static, none of the other variables. There's actually no need to split the declarations. -1.

Comment: Do you know something about readability & the so-called Pareto Principle?

Comment: @RorrohProger me? I know that repeating yourself unnecessarily makes you harder to understand. I know that claiming something that is false as if it were universally true is misleading. And I know that keeping all of the variables static was enough for my -1 in any case.